# What KNN accuracy is shown here?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I use the knn algorithm from the sklearn library. In the last code line, I get a result for accurency with 95,5%. Does that mean, that 95,5% of my test dataset **X_test** is right/correct predicted?

Here I short part of my script.

```
# Model, predict and solve
X_train = train_df.drop("Survived", axis=1)
Y_train = train_df["Survived"]
X_test  = test_df.drop("PassengerId", axis=1).copy()
X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_test.shape

# KNN
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
acc_knn = round(knn.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
acc_knn
```

How can I see the wrong predicted rows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your predictions are in the `Y_pred` variable. Print it along with the `y_test` variable. You can then compare and see which observations are correctly predicted and which are incorrectly classified.

PS: From your code snippet, its not clear whether you do have  `y_test` variable.